# Skimage's cut_normalized return a single label

Tags: image-processing, scikit-learn, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I'm trying to learn how to segment an image using Normalization Cut. My problem is that I would use superpixel and then NCUT, but the `cut_normalized` method gives me a single value, and so if I plot it, I have a single color, as follows:

[image: img]

This is my code:

```py
def normcut_segmentations(img):
    labels, superpixels = get_super_pixels(img)
    g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels, mode='similarity')
    ncuts_labels = graph.cut_normalized(labels, g)
    print("Segmentation label: ", np.unique(labels))
    print("NCUTs Label:",np.unique(ncuts_labels))
    ncuts_result = color.label2rgb(ncuts_labels, img, kind='avg')
    return ncuts_labels,ncuts_result
```

To read the image (that is a bitmap), I use `skimage.io.imread(img_filename)`.

What would be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: please include the input image in your question to form the [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: try using `graph.show_rag` to visualize the graph if it makes sense. You might to tweak the `sigma` parameter of `rag_mean_color`.